# Why can't I see my Indexed DB in Firefox dev tools?

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I have been developing a little speed dial page to learn how to work with IndexedDB. It's a locally hosted html page. When I open the page in Firefox, and attempt to inspect the Indexed DB the page creates, in the developer tools (under storage), it doesn't show any Databases. However, the page is successfully able to access and work with the DB (everything is loaded, and saved when the browser is closed). When I try it in Chrome, it shows the DB in the developer tools, and I am able to inspect the entries.

I am using the latest version of FF (56.0), but already had this issue with the previous version (55).

Has anyone else had issues with not being able to see Indexed DBs in Firefox developer tools? Does anyone know how to fix this, or is this a Firefox bug?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm having this issue as well and came across your question trying to solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've kept my Firefox up to date since then, but I still have the exact same issue, and I wasn't able to find any answers anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been resolved by a Firefox update. I am now running Version 61.0.2, and I can now see the Indexed DB and all the entries in the developer tools, under Storage.

Answer (score 0):

[Resetting of the profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) helped me.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that a recent Firefox update has fixed the issue. See my answer below.